# Kafka producer on Google App Engine

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, subprocess, apache-kafka

I have a python **google app engine** project. I wanted to integrate **kafka producer** into that project using library kafka-python(I am perfectly able to run kafka-python via python console directly). While running on local using Google App engine SDK i am getting following error in python2.7 multiprocessing library:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
File "/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
File "/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
obj = __import__(path[0])
File "/Users/nilaysahu/Documents/abc/booking_management/main.py", line 29, in <module>
from modules.booking.handlers.test_handler import TestHandler
File "/Users/nilaysahu/Documents/abc/booking_management/modules/booking/handlers/test_handler.py", line 5, in <module>
**from kafka import KafkaProducer**
File "/Users/nilaysahu/Documents/abc/booking_management/lib/kafka/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
from kafka.consumer import KafkaConsumer
File "/Users/nilaysahu/Documents/abc/booking_management/lib/kafka/consumer/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
from .multiprocess import MultiProcessConsumer
File "/Users/nilaysahu/Documents/abc/booking_management/lib/kafka/consumer/multiprocess.py", line 5, in <module>
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager as MPManager
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/__init__.py", line 65, in <module>
from multiprocessing.util import SUBDEBUG, SUBWARNING
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/util.py", line 41, in <module>
from subprocess import _args_from_interpreter_flags
**ImportError: cannot import name _args_from_interpreter_flags**
```

1. Is there any problem with my local framework?
2. Does google app engine (not compute engine) support kafka?

Comment: Did you vendor in necessary packages in your app? https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#installing_a_library

Comment: Yes @DanCornilescu